# I can't create login in django 1.10.1 version

Tags: python, django

I know it is basic to create login User Authentication. And I am a newbie here in using Django.

I have a problem in creating User Authentication:

Views.py

```
def Logins(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('music/login')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('music/login')
form = Userlogin
return render(request, 'music/login.html', {'Login_form': Userlogin})
```

urls.py
    url(r'^login/$', views.Logins, name='login'),

It shows
    [It shows MultiValueDictKeyError at /music/login/.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI0cG.jpg)
    "'username'"
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/login/
    Django Version: 1.10.4
    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
    Exception Value:
    "'username'"

login.html

```
{% block body %}
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Something is wrong</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="email">Login:</label>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="username">

    <input type="submit" value="login" />

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MultiValueDictKeyError` seems to be because `request.POST['username']` does not exist.

Add a username field in your login form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label for="email">Login:</label>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="username">
    <input type="submit" value="login" />

</form>
```

Comment: thank you bro. but after that it now produce = 'method' object is not subscriptable= error. :( what should I do?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` is a dictionary. You should be doing it this way:

```
username = request.POST.get('username', None)
password = request.POST.get('password', None)
```